# Handling success and failure API JSON responses when json format is different for each

Tags: c#, json.net, async-await

How do I handle a failure when my method only returns a single return type?

```
 public async Task<User> GetUser(int userId)
{
    User user = null;
    HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("/User/...");
    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        var result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        user = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<User>(result);
    }
    else
    {
        // ????
    }

    return user;
}
```

Success:

```
{
    "a": 1,
    "b": 2,
    "c": 3
}
```

Failure

```
{
    "error": "something has gone wrong..."
}
```

In the failure case currently I am just returning null, but I want to return the error message.

The API I am using doesn't return the same JSON for both failure and success, so I'm not sure how to best handle the failure case.

Comment: You could return a `Tuple<string, User>` or create a class with the properties, but this really has nothing to do with JSON

Comment: It is common to set an appropriate Http Status code and base some logic around it. So on success maybe use `200`, for failure use something in the `400`'s as appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

@Crowcoder's comment is the proper route. However, in case you ever had a successful response with a dynamic object structure this information could be useful. You can test a property on a returned object to see if it is `undefined`. In your case, and don't do this because you should use the status codes, you could do something like this:

```
if(result.error){
    //this is an error state
} else {
    //this was successful
}
```